# How to get the images from JSON into a grid view in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, getjson

Can any one give me good example for the JSON format consisting of images into a grid view? I know how to get it from a URL but its static so I need it dynamically like when the new image is uploaded to the server then the image should be displayed on the apps screen on refreshing.

Can anyone say how to do this?

Comment: using the android image url i got the images but its static but i need it in dynamic

Comment: You can find a nice and easy example here https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial it'll help you.
using Grid view:
[http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-gridview-tutorial/](http://Tutorial%201:%20Grid%20View)

using listview: 
[http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/](http://Tutorial%202)

Comment: the images are in the url in the following state  {"Categories":[{"Category_ID":"1001","Prod_ID":"101","Prod_Title":"Apple Acces1","Prod_Desc":"Apple Desc-01","Prod_Image":"----url----\/products\/Product1.jpg", like this

Comment: Are your images in android local storage?

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "images": [
        "url1",
        "url2",
        "url3",
        "url4"
    ]
}
```

so whenever new image is uploaded just append the filename of the image on server with say ,current time in ms and update the db with current url.

So , if you are using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) the change in url will automatically load a new image in the grid